# Attempting to Parse an XLS (XML) File Using Python

Tags: python, excel, xml, pandas, netsuite

I have an "XLS" file that I downloaded from Netsuite ERP. The file root says ".XLS" but it's actually an XML file. I have a pandas script that will combine several XLS or XLSX files but pandas can't seem to handle this weird XLS/XML file type, so I have another script attempting to parse the XML data and save to XLS or XLSX. The below script doesn't seem to work however, as it results in "None". Could anyone point me in the right direction, either with my sample code, new code, or a new method for solving this odd XLS/XML parsing issue?

Thank you in advance!

XML Sample Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <Author>NetSuite Reports</Author>
    <LastAuthor>NetSuite Reports</LastAuthor>
    <Company>NetSuite</Company>
  </DocumentProperties>
  <Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="company">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" />
      <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="subcompany">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" />
      <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="error">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" />
      <Interior ss:Color="#f0d0d0" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
      <Font ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="header_l">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" />
      <Font ss:Size="7" ss:Bold="1" />
      <Interior ss:Color="#d0d0d0" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="header_r">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" />
      <Font ss:Size="7" ss:Bold="1" />
      <Interior ss:Color="#d0d0d0" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="header_c">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" />
      <Font ss:Size="7" ss:Bold="1" />
      <Interior ss:Color="#d0d0d0" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="scheckbox">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Center" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
      <Borders />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" />
      <Interior />
      <NumberFormat />
      <Protection />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s53">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Left" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Dash" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#cccccc" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s52">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="1" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s51">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Right" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0" />
      <NumberFormat ss:Format="&quot;€&quot;#,##0.00" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s50">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Left" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s58">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="2" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Dash" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#cccccc" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s54">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Right" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <NumberFormat ss:Format="&quot;€&quot;#,##0.00" />
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Dash" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#cccccc" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s59">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="1" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Dash" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#cccccc" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s56">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="2" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s57">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="3" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s55">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="1" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s60">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Left" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Dash" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#cccccc" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
  </Styles>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="TrialBalance">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="company" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Parent Company</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="company" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Company Holdings Inc. : Company A  B.V.</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="subcompany" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Trial Balance</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="subcompany" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String">End of Feb 2020</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="subcompany" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String" />
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="subcompany" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String" />
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="header_l">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Account</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="header_r" ss:MergeDown="0" ss:Index="2">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Total</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s50">
          <Data ss:Type="String">10000 - CASH &amp; CASH EQUIVALENTS</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s51" />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s52">
          <Data ss:Type="String">10101 - Bank - 9999 - Company A - EUR</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s51">
          <Data ss:Type="Number">1234567.01</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s53">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Total - 10000 - CASH &amp; CASH EQUIVALENTS</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:Formula="SUM(R[-1]C)" ss:StyleID="s54">
          <Data ss:Type="Number">1234567.01</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Python Code Parsing XML to XLS:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(r"C:\Users\NAME\Documents\rootfolder\examplefile.xls")
root = tree.getroot()

def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
    return node.text if node is not None else None


def main():
    """ main """
    parsed_xml = tree
    dfcols = ['account', 'total']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)


for node in parsed_xml.getroot():
    account = node.attrib.get('Type="String"')
    total = node.find('Type="Number"')

    df_xml = df_xml.append(
        pd.Series([account, getvalueofnode(total)], index=dfcols),
        ignore_index=True)

print(df_xml)


main()
```

Python Parsing XML File Results:

```
  account total
0    None  None
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avoid building a data frame by appending objects like Series or even DataFrames. Instead, build a list of dictionaries to be binded to `DataFrame`. Additionally, because your XML has a default namespace, you must assign a prefix to parse any element under the namespace

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

ns = {"doc": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"}

tree = ET.parse(r"C:\Path\To\Input.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
    return node.text if node is not None else None


def main():
    """ main """
    parsed_xml = tree

    data = []
    for i, node in enumerate(root.findall('.//doc:Row', ns)):
        if i > 6:
            data.append({'account': getvalueofnode(node.find('doc:Cell[1]/doc:Data', ns)),
                         'total': getvalueofnode(node.find('doc:Cell[2]/doc:Data', ns))})

    return(pd.DataFrame(data))

output_df = main()

print(output_df)
#                                    account       total
# 0          10000 - CASH & CASH EQUIVALENTS        None
# 1    10101 - Bank - 9999 - Company A - EUR  1234567.01
# 2  Total - 10000 - CASH & CASH EQUIVALENTS  1234567.01
```

Alternatively, save your Excel styled XML as `xlsx` with [Workbook.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) method using `win32com` (only for Windows users) and read in with [**`pandas.read_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) skipping appropriate rows.

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd

# SAVE EXCEL FILE
try:
    xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Path\To\Input.xml")
    xlWbk.SaveAs(r"C:\Path\To\Output.xlsx", 51)

    xlWbk.Close(True)
    xlApp.Quit()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    xlWbk = None; xlApp = None
    del xlWbk; del xlApp

# READ EXCEL FILE
output_df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Path\To\Output.xlsx", skiprows = 6)

print(output_df)    
#                                    Account       Total
# 0          10000 - CASH & CASH EQUIVALENTS         NaN
# 1    10101 - Bank - 9999 - Company A - EUR  1234567.01
# 2  Total - 10000 - CASH & CASH EQUIVALENTS  1234567.01
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful thank you. I quickly gave your 2nd solution a try and it worked wonderfully. I'm still learning Python and am curious which method would you recommend following if my ultimate goal is to combine several "XML" type files into one? 2nd solution seems more elegant and easy to follow.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help. I recommend whatever works for you. Though the XML might be more lightweight as you do not interact with the Excel application. But if XMLs change dramatically, second option might be best.

Comment: You bet, just marked as an answer. Would your recommendation change if I was trying to execute a for loop, parsing through multiple XML files in a directory to augment them to xlsx format?

Comment: That might be a different question but has been asked many times. Look into `os.listdir` or `glob` loops across files in directory. Then simply integrate here, passing in file names with each iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Parfait. The second code is ok and working on my side. Is there another way to convert to xlsx except using win32com?